# (No tasks found) message in task runner explorer VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, gulp

I have task which generates CSS from LESS. It worked perfectly but I found out that it doesn't work now. I found some questions here but they weren't helpful for me. Could you tell me what can be the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xIYO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that "node_modules" was missing in my project. I added it and task runner worked correctly.

Comment: You don't need `node_modules` in your `.csproj` project and I would highly advice against it. For me just unloading/reloading the project was enough

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's task runner will not recognize gulp tasks unless your project is not actually a project but a website.

Right click your solution -> Add -> New Website ...

**A word of caution**

Make sure your source control does not pick up your node packages automatically or you are in for some major headakes